# Fixing/adding module imports for entire workspace

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode to build a larger TypeScript application. Let's say one day I decide to use absolute paths for module imports, because I want to be more directory structure agnostic. So I add the appropriate configuration, also configure vscode to prefer non-relative imports.

But I end up with lots of already existing imports in every file, which is a huge work to manually fix. What I can do file by file is delete all imports, and use the automatic imports for that file. Still, I have to do this for every piece of source file, which is still a nightmare.

Is anyone aware of any kinds of built-in or extension tooling which can help in situation like this? What I could image is something that *resets* all the imports in every file and re-imports automatically everything, based on the new settings.

Comment: Not that I could find, I recently ran into something similar, changed my baseUrl prop in tsconfig to "app" so I could import everything off it's direct children instead of using relative '../../someFolder".Best I was able to do was go file by file deleting all the imports and let VSCode "import all missing" with the shorthand paths.